# How to write a function that changes the order of DataFrame columns? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The function should move the 'profit' column to the beginning

```
<pre><code>
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 10], [4, 5, 20], [7, 8, 30]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'profit'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 20], [4, 5, 30], [7, 8, 40]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'profit'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 30], [4, 5, 40], [7, 8, 50]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'profit'])

def move_col(got_df):
    cols = list(got_df)
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('profit')))
    got_df = got_df.loc[:, cols]

move_col(df1)
df1
</pre></code>
```

I don't see any changes.
Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may considering posting a little example of the column data as it is and how you want it as output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line you call the function to:

```
df1 = move_col(df1)
```

and you need to add a return.

so your code should be:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 10], [4, 5, 20], [7, 8, 30]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'profit'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 20], [4, 5, 30], [7, 8, 40]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'profit'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 30], [4, 5, 40], [7, 8, 50]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'profit'])

def move_col(got_df):
    cols = list(got_df)
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('profit')))
    return got_df.loc[:, cols]

df1 = move_col(df1)
df1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding a return statement would achieve what you intend:

```
def move_col(got_df):
    cols = list(got_df)
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('profit')))
    got_df = got_df.loc[:, cols]
    return got_df

df=move_col(df1)
print(df)
```